# How to obtain all children of a Form in RAD Studio designer code?

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio

I would be glad if someone could help me in completing this tiny task:

I want to get a list of all child elements in a Form.

`TCustomForm` has a `GetChildren()` method that I found in the docs, but I do not understand what the first argument is used for, nor do I understand why I should insert a reference to the calling instance of `TCustomForm` as the second argument. In addition, I have no hint what to expect as the returned value.

I simply do not know how to use this method properly. Can someone give me an example? This is what I am missing in the documentation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st parameter of `GetChildren()` is a pointer to a callback method.  You pass in a method that you want `GetChildren()` to call for each child object, eg:

```
void __fastcall TMyClass::GetChildProc(TComponent *Child)
{
    // do something with Child...
}

void __fastcall TMyClass::DoSomething()
{
    //...
    SomeForm->GetChildren(&GetChildProc, SomeForm);
    //...
}
```

Note, however, that the callback is invoked only for child components whose [`HasParent()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.HasParent) method returns `false` (ie, for non-UI components, or for `TControl` descendants whose [`Parent`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Parent) property is `NULL`).  IOW, `GetChildren()` is typically used only by the DFM streaming system to discover a Form's *non-visual* components that are not children of the Form's UI window at runtime.  Which is why the documentation suggests you not call `GetChildren()` directly:

> GetChildren is used internally in the component streaming system. It is not necessary to call it directly.

That being said, all components placed on a Form at design-time are *owned* by the Form.  So, you could just enumerate the Form's *owned* components directly via its [`Components[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Components) property, eg:

```
void __fastcall TMyClass::DoSomething()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SomeForm->ComponentCount; ++i)
    {
        TComponent *Child = SomeForm->Components[i];
        // do something with Child...
    }
}
```

This is essentially what `GetChildren()` does internally when the `Root` parameter is set to the Form itself.